# How to replace element in body tag in Angular2

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular

Best way to replace XML string into the `body` tag rather than using jQuery `$('body').html(string)`

Trying to replace the body element on click event with the XML string below.

```
xmlStringReplace() {
     let xmlString = '<xml id="POSCMD" LateProcessing="true"><commands>
 <injectfieldmacro type="field" name="FIELD_CLEAR"></injectfieldmacro>';
     for (let item of itemCode) {
       xmlString += '<injectdata type="literal" data="' + item + '">
 </injectdata>';
       xmlString += '<injectfieldmacro type="field" name="FIELD_UPC">
 </injectfieldmacro>';
     }
     xmlString += '</commands></xml>';
     $('body').html(xmlString);
}
```

Is there a better way of doing the above code in Angular2?

Can try this, but this is just appending to `div` and I get `sanitizing HTML stripped`.. in the console.log as well.

```
 this.xmlStringPOS = '<xml id="POSCMD" LateProcessing="true"><commands><injectfieldmacro type="field" name="FIELD_CLEAR"></injectfieldmacro>';
for (let item of itemCode) {
  this.xmlStringPOS += '<injectdata type="literal" data="' + item + '"></injectdata>';
  this.xmlStringPOS += '<injectfieldmacro type="field" name="FIELD_UPC"></injectfieldmacro>';
}
this.xmlStringPOS += '</commands></xml>';

`<div [innerHtml]="xmlString "></div>`
```

Comment: You're replacing html In your jquery example. Do you want to append to body or replace html? Create root component with selector 'body' and use `@HostBinding` to apply string to `innerHTML` property

Comment: The first code block you posted should work fine if you place it in your ngOnInit() function (assuming it works as planned in a plain javascript environment).

Comment: @yurzui sorry yeah i meant replace not append.

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/ludzyGkJGhMidxArSUfD?p=preview

Comment: @yurzui will it work still if the replace happens on click event? rather than `onInit`

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/QtBlVvdjzIKIb68pivav?p=preview